# Run single Grails unit/integration test will run all the tests on Intellij

Tags: unit-testing, grails, intellij-idea

Sometimes, when I run a single Grails unit or integration test on Intellij (latest version), it will run all the tests in the console.

What I do is right click single unit test class or method in the code and select run.

Sometimes it happened but sometimes it is OK.

Anyone has idea how to fix or prevent this  happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be IntellijIdea issue. I'd suggest to use grails command prompt for testing. Just use:

```
grails test-app unit: YourTestClass
```

or

```
grails test-app integration: YourIntegrationTestClass
```

This works for me.

Comment: I found grails 3.x has a slightly different command line syntax:  "grails test-app -integration YourIntegrationTestSpec"